# how to get last insert id after insert query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I'm having problem with my controller, I return the the last id I've inserted in the model

```
public function insert_cropsci($question_data) {    
    $this->db->insert('cropscience_bank', $question_data);
    $questionid =$this->db->insert_id();
    return $questionid;
}
```

but don't know how to get the id(id only) in my controller

My Controller:

```
switch ($subject) {
    case 1:
        $this->load->model('insertquestion_model');
        $this->insertquestion_model->insert_cropsci($question_data);
        //I don't know what to do here to get the id(id only)
    break;
}
```

need some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to assign value in variable after assigning you will able to use it.

```
switch ($subject) {
            case 1:
                $this->load->model('insertquestion_model');
                $id = $this->insertquestion_model->insert_cropsci($question_data);
                echo $id;
                break;
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$this->db->insert('table', $data);
$insert_id = $this->db->insert_id();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
switch ($subject) {
case 1:
    $this->load->model('insertquestion_model');
    $id=$this->insertquestion_model->insert_cropsci($question_data);
    $id=$_SESSION['id'];
    // My be you can save as a session, use id in other form
break;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You already have your value available, you just don't store it in a variable, from what I've seen looking at your code.

```
switch ($subject) {
    case 1:
        $this->load->model('insertquestion_model');
        $modelId = $this->insertquestion_model->insert_cropsci($question_data);
        // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ return the $modelId from your controller!
        break;
```